# Streaming Google Speech api

Tags: java, google-api, speech-recognition

currently I can recognize speech to text using google's speech api. Now that I have this, I was just wondering if there is a way I can stream the response of transcribed text and give it more text to transcribe at the same time. In other words I want to speak into the microphone, and as I speak I want a response from the google servers. The code I am using currently:

```
System.out.println("openning connection");
HttpsURLConnection httpConn = null;
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
byte[] destdata = new byte[2048];
int resCode = -1;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpsURLConnection)) {
        throw new IOException ("URL must be HTTPS");
    }
    httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection)urlConn;
    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("AcceptEncoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
    httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0); //TransferType: chunked
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/l16; rate=" + sampleRate);
    // this opens a connection, then sends POST & headers.
    out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    //beyond 15 sec duration just simply writing the file
    // does not seem to work. So buffer it and delay to simulate
    // bufferd microphone delivering stream of speech
    // re: net.http.ChunkedOutputStream.java
    while(buff.remaining() >= destdata.length){
        buff.get(destdata);
        out.write(destdata);
    };
    byte[] lastr = new byte[buff.remaining()];
    buff.get(lastr, 0, lastr.length);
    out.write(lastr);
    out.close();
    resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if(resCode >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED){//Stops here if Google doesn't like us/
        System.out.println("unauthorized");
        throw new HTTPException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);//Throws
    }
    String line;//Each line that is read back from Google.
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = br.readLine( )) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if(line.length()>19 && resCode > 100 && resCode < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED){
            GoogleResponse gr = new GoogleResponse();
            parseResponse(line, gr);
            fireResponseEvent(gr);
        }
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {httpConn.disconnect();}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution?